# how to combine multiple charts with same x-axis (stacking two charts) in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have 3 time series data with wildly different data ranges. I can show two of them using a primary and secondary y-axis but that does not work well with the third data series.

In Excel is it possible to combine two charts such that they share the same x-axis, i.e. two different origins. Is there a limit - could three charts be stacked this way?

Thanks a lot

Comment: In first paragraph you write about y axis, but second paragraph contain x axis. Please clarify your question. What type of chart do you want to use? Also adding singer sample days could help understanding your question.

Comment: If your data is that varied and you want a single chart, consider a LOG scale for your Y Axis.  Rather than having multiple axis, consider using three separate charts in a panel/small multiples configuration to show the data, each to its own scale, but in relation to the other data sets.

Comment: @dav that's ideal, and will work even without using LOG scale... Is it possible to have the three separate charts in panel use the same x-axis?

Answer (score 3):

As discussed briefly in the comments, there are at least two possible solutions:

Assuming three data sets like this:

[image: multi-scale range]

First, a single chart with a log formatted axis.  This will work well if your data are simple and/or your audience is educated/prepared to read and understand it.  Simply re-format your axis to an appropriate log and you'll get this:

[image: multi-scale log]

If you're not sure your audience will understand the log scale, you can use a panel chart approach.  Here are three identical charts, each with one data set and the appropriate Y axis scale:

[image: multi-scale panel]

To create this effect, just create/format your first chart with your first series, then duplicate (or copy/paste) the first chart for each series.  Then change the Y-series data and make sure the Y axis is formatted properly.